# Vue watch still fires vuex action after updating vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex

Hi guys I'm having trouble about my little project, so basically I just need to show to the user the sign up modal if they are not signed in when they click any item on my page. The problem is after they signed in the sign up modal still shows when they click something which should not be since the already signed in.

Here are my codes

SignupModal.vue

```
axios.get('/user/sign-up', {
        params:{
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            phone: this.phone,
            age: this.age,
            city: this.city,
        }
    })
    .then( (response) => {
        if( response.status == 200 ) {
            $('#modals-signup').modal('hide')
            this.$store.commit( 'UPDATE_USER_LOGIN_STATE' )
        }
    });
```

HomePage.vue

```
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            loginState: this.$store.state.isLoggedIn
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            'isLoggedIn'
        ]),
    },
    watch: {
        isLoggedIn( newVal, oldVal ) {
            this.loginState = newVal
            console.log('HOME PAGE WATCH ==================' + newVal + ' ===== ' +this.loginState)

            if ( this.loginState ) {
                console.log('true since its logged in')
                return 
            }
            else {
                console.log('false since its logged out')
                this.$store.dispatch('preventClickingItems')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Store.js

```
    const state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
}

const getters = {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => state.isLoggedIn
}

const actions = {
    preventClickingItems: ( {commit} ) => {
        $('section').on('click', 'div.container *', (e) => {
            $('#modals-signup').modal('show')
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
            return false
        })
    }
}

const mutations = {
    UPDATE_USER_LOGIN_STATE( state ) {
        state.isLoggedIn = !state.isLoggedIn
        console.log('===========', state.isLoggedIn)
    }
}


export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
    plugins: [vuexCookie.plugin]
})
```

I was able to update the state after user is signed in and able to execute the if block only from the watch, but I dont understand why it still triggers the modal since it only runs the if block.

Comment: Just a thought but can't see you hiding the modal anywhere

Comment: @AliK I have updated the code, modal hide triggers when request status is 200

Comment: I would not use a computed or watch also would not bind click event to entire div.container just a button and in that button click logic show the box based on login state.  Not sure if it helps but might point you in right direction also take a look at [this](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/building-a-modal-dialog-with-vue-and-vuex/).

Comment: @AliK I know it's not a good thing to bind the click event in the container but this needs to appy in all pages and each page have different contents that's why I did it.  The way I solved if is to check the state value inside the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding if else statement inside the click event to check the isLoggedIn state value

```
const actions = {
    preventClickingItems: ( {commit, state} ) => {
        $('section').on('click', 'div.container *', (e) => {
            if ( state.isLoggedIn ) {
                return
            }
            else {
                $('#modals-signup').modal('show')
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopPropagation()
                return false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to see you have solved it, just FYI there was a link in my last comment, hope you did not miss it.